# Eclipse (Mars) not getting started after a java Upgrade

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

When I am starting the eclipse I am getting this error. -vm argument contains the path of the java.exe which is not their in my system possible after a java upgrade. How Can I correct this?
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:/ProgramData/Oracle/java/javapath/java.exe....
This path does not exist in my system

Eclipse.INI contents are

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 512M
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 512m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your eclipse.ini

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

Comment: Please edit your question and put the eclipse.ini contents there. Line breaks are important in this file and we can't see them in a comment.

Comment: You are starting a 64 bit Eclipse, is your Java 64 bit? Both Java and Eclipse must be either 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: My JVM seems to be 32 bit and Eclipse is definitely 64 bit may that is the reason and earlier location it referred must have had 64 bit Java which got uninstalled in whole upgrade process somewhere. I guess I will just download the 32 bit version of Eclipse Mars and that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JVM seems to be 32 bit and Eclipse is definitely 64 bit may that is the reason and earlier location it referred must have had 64 bit Java which got uninstalled in whole upgrade process somewhere. I guess I will just download the 32 bit version of Eclipse Mars and that would solve the problem. –

Answer (score 3):

```
osgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

this line specifies to use Java 6. If you upgraded JAVA you should update this field.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM